# Why does google sheets have a pop up formula box does any one actually use this box is there a way to disable it,

Tags: google-sheets

[image: picture of offending box]The extra formula box that pops up on google sheets is easily one of the dumbest and most annoying features I have encountered while using google sheets and I am surprised nobody else seems to talk about it. Am I missing something it constantly has me scrolling to look behind it to see the information on the sheet I am writing a formula for. Does anyone actually use this feature and if so why? I cant find a way to disable it.

Comment: While an image might be helpful, sample data and formulas should be included as text. Also questions about spreadsheet formulas should describe the relevant parts of the spreadsheet including spreadsheet settings like the spreadsheet locale as it affects the function parameter separator among other things.

Answer (score 0):

You are not missing anything. There are many people using the formula box. There is no way to disable the formula box in Google Sheets.

It is a matter of taste whether a user prefers the formula box or the formula bar at the top. Both are standard features in spreadsheet programs.

The logic in the formula you show in the screenshot seems unnecessarily complex. There would probably be a way to rewrite it in a much less convoluted way so that it fits on perhaps three short lines, which would make the box less trouble.

Comment: Please illuminate I am always looking to simplify and am completely self taught.

Comment: Please ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741). If you choose to post another question, consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with _realistic-looking_ data, and showing your _manually entered_ desired results there.